# Solution of a matrix equation with a triangular matrix

Tags: systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Given the matrix:
$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
       b_1 & 0 & 0& ...           \\[0.3em]
       b_2 & b_1     &0      & ... \\[0.3em]
       b_3           & b_2 & b_1 \\... & ...&...&...\\b_N &b_{N-1} &... & b_1
     \end{bmatrix}$$
I need to solve the following matrix equation:
$B\dot{}B^T=I$ where $I$ is the unit matrix. The $b_k$ are the unknown coefficients.
How can I solve it?

Comment: Maybe I'm glancing too quick, but I think $B$ times the first column of $B^T$ allows $B=\pm I$ to be immediately deduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have :

$$ B B^{\top} = \begin{bmatrix} b_{1}^{2} & b_{1}b_{2} & \ldots & b_{1}b_{n} \\ \ast & \ldots & \ldots & \ast \\ \vdots & & & \vdots \\ \ast & \ldots & \ldots & \ast \end{bmatrix} $$

Identifying $BB^{\top}$ with the identity matrix (just identify the first line of $BB^{\top}$ with the first line of the identity matrix) leads to :

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
b_{1} = \pm 1 \\[2mm]
b_{2} = 0 \\[2mm]
\vdots \\[2mm]
b_{n} = 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

As a consequence, $B=\pm I$.

Comment: Thanks, but this is the trivial solution. It's one of the possible solutions I think.

Comment: I do not see any other solution because the equality $BB^{\top}=I$ is equivalent to $b_{1}^{2}=1$ and $\forall i \in \lbrace 2,\ldots,n \rbrace, \, b_{i}=0$.